# How to iterate the id of an altbeacon?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, altbeacon

I am trying to do some testing and I want to iterate the id of my advertising beacon.  I cant initiate a beacon in a loop and startadvertising because the beacon will never iterate.  Is there a way I can just send out one advertisement, iterate the id and send out another advertisement and so on?

Comment: Are you saying you want to transmit as a beacon with the identifier incrementing over time?  Can you show the code you have now?

Comment: Yes, I am playing around with some different networking ideas and it would be helpful if I could see if I am missing any advertisements.  If I could make the ID or any part of the advertisement iterate, this would allow me to determine if I am missing any advertisements.

Answer (score 0):

Advertisements are sent out at various configurable rates by the Android operating system, so you don't have full control over each packet.   You can, however, set up a timer that increments the transmitted identifier every second or so like this:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
private void incrementIdentifierAndTransmitBeacon(final int identifier) {
    Beacon beacon = new Beacon.Builder()
            .setId1("2f234454-cf6d-4a0f-adf2-f4911ba9ffa6")
            .setId2("1")
            .setId3(new Integer(identifier).toString())
            .setManufacturer(0x0118) // Radius Networks.  Change this for other beacon layouts
            .setTxPower(-59)
            .setDataFields(Arrays.asList(new Long[]{0l})) // Remove this for beacon layouts without d: fields
            .build();
    BeaconParser beaconParser = new BeaconParser()
            .setBeaconLayout(BeaconParser.ALTBEACON_LAYOUT);
    BeaconTransmitter beaconTransmitter = new BeaconTransmitter(getApplicationContext(), beaconParser);
    beaconTransmitter.stopAdvertising();
    beaconTransmitter.startAdvertising(beacon, new AdvertiseCallback() {

    });
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            incrementIdentifierAndTransmitBeacon((identifier+1) % 65536);
        }
    }, 1000l);

}
```